# CentOS reboot apperently with no reason

Tags: centos, linux

My server has restarted and I can't find a reason for this...if you have any tips on what things should I search it will be appreciated.

Few info about server:
- CentOS release 5.6 (Final)

What I've done so far:

- last reboot | head 
  reboot   system boot  2.6.18-xxx Mon Oct  3 12:32          (00:45)
- used sensors to see if the problem was because of high temp but when i checked(~3-5 min after the reboot) temperature was Core 0:      +65°C
- in /var/log/messages i have no info about reboot ...so here are few lines from messages:

  ```
  Oct  2 20:50:01 p07 auditd[6738]: Audit daemon rotating log files
  Oct  3 07:58:14 p07 auditd[6738]: Audit daemon rotating log files
  Oct  3 12:32:40 p07 syslogd 1.4.1: restart.
  Oct  3 12:32:40 p07 kernel: klogd 1.4.1, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
  Oct  3 12:32:40 p07 kernel: Linux version 2.6.18-xxx (root@rhel5-build-x64) #1 SMP Thu Jul 21 19:23:22 MSD 2011
  Oct  3 12:32:40 p07 kernel: Command line: ro root=/dev/md2 selinux=0
  Oct  3 12:32:40 p07 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
  ```

Comment: Have a look in `/var/log/kern.log` Hopefully, any kernel oops messages or other indications of failure will be logged in there. Add the lines to your original post if you see anything that looks suspicious.

Comment: hello i don't have kern.log ...and in messages nothing above those lines appear. Maybe there is nothing to do in this situation :(

Comment: Is this is a chronic problem or is this the first occurance?

Comment: you need to configure your syslog to log kernel log messages to a file, 'man syslog' read on facilities . logging kernel related messages might help you debug more. Did you add some hardware/software to the to the server recently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. try to enter the BMC log and see if there has been a hardware error that caused the reboot (log locations and their interpretation are probably best asked from the HW vendor)
2. Does the server have a fence device? Any chance it has been fenced?
3. If you have a smart PDU, there might be logs for power outages in there. If the server is hosted with a managed server farm, I'd ask the NOC team about outages as well

Answer (score 1):

your server is really server or desktop computer with linux?

1. you can try to test memory with memtest.
2. you can try to update bios.
3. did server have UPS ?
4. power supply may fail...

where server is located? under your table or in server room with air conditioner ?

Comment: It is a server and it's located with other servers in a room with air conditioner.

Comment: try to test memory with memtest 5 or more cycles.